# Batch-install programs

Tags: gratis, windows-7, automation

I am looking for a tool that **allows me to input installers** (.exe and .msi files), and it **outputs a single .exe** file that can be run on any Windows system to *automatically* install all the programs I originally inputted.

I want:

- no confirmation boxes (I should be able to go away for an hour or so, and come back with everything installed)
- it to be free
- it to run on Windows 7 64 bit
- it to be ***automatic***
- the final .exe to be as small as possible (compressed) *if possible*

This will be helpful for reinstalling Windows every so often.

Comment: for a small subset of software, I can think of a few things that may work. The fact that you want to install *arbitrary* software is tricky.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek How else could I do this? If I don't choose the .exe's, how will a new installer be made?

Comment: I'm thinking chocolatey (which works like apt-get) or ninite (the free version lets you tick off what you want to install)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I am not a linux user so I have no idea about 'apt -get' - I've only ever heard about it on SU, but I've ignored it. Ninite looks like exactly what I want, but I want a bigger variety - I use some unpopular programs that Ninite does not have. I never knew about Ninite, so thanks! **But, I'd rather have a program where I could choose *any .exe* files and get an installer out of them.**

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue. Different windows installers have different silent install methods so there's no universal one I know of. Would be glad to be proven wrong though!

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I hope you are ;)

Comment: I don't see many more options though http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems#Microsoft_Windows :/

Comment: @ṧнʊß Another idea: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10053/903

Comment: Well... I did find [this](http://emcosoftware.com/msi-package-builder) but its a little [pricey](http://emcosoftware.com/msi-package-builder/purchase)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yep, that's perfect!

Comment: @aman207 THanks for your answer on Franck's question!