# Integrating applications into a Windows 7 disc

Tags: windows-7

I am looking for a program that can integrate applications into a Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate installation ISO. Just like [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/) can do with Windows XP (using [pre-existing nLite Addons](http://www.winaddons.com/nlite-addons) or [creating new ones](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/63596-how-to-create-your-own-add-ons-zcworld-video/)). Free is better.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can give [RT Se7en Lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/) a try. Personally I have used this to aid with the installation of a new computer for my Dad, since it can take a lot of time to reinstall everything and you can miss certain programs.

> RT Se7en Lite is developed by Rockers Team to customize windows 7 operating system and to make it lite. You can add wallpapers, Icons, themes, integrate updates, drivers, language packs, applications, remove components, enable or disable features, unattended installation settings, bootable ISO and USB creator , etc. It will be very easy to operate and changing the style of your windows 7 operating system.

Features:

- Add Windows programs automatically, just like how nLite did
- Works with all editions of Windows 7 (except server editions)
- Easy step-by-step instructions
- Add Windows updates, hot fixes, driver, and language packs
- Remove Windows components to make the installation smaller
- Change system settings before booting up Windows for the first time
- Can make the installation unattended (so no need for user input at all)
- Can pre customize desktop backgrounds, themes, colours etc
- Create a bootable .ISO and can split the image if needed (useful if for some reason the computer doesn't have a DVD drive)
- Best of all, its 100% free (donations accepted)

Its important to note that this only works with Windows 7 Desktop and not with Windows Vista or 8.

Here is a [Life hacker](http://lifehacker.com/5894838/customize-your-windows-installation-to-create-the-os-of-your-dreams) tutorial on how to use it if you wish.

Screenshots:

Making the image

[image: Making the image]

Task selection

[image: Task selection]